# Tailwind config not exporting all css

Tags: html, css, npm, tailwind-css, npx

I am trying to publish the full tailwind 3.0 css library in a fresh laravel 8.* project with the view to use the [corePlugins](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#core-plugins) section to remove what I do not need. The thing is although the setup was quick, I can not get the complete tailwind css styles published in the public `app.css` file; only the base styles get published. So what am I doing wrong?
  I started with `npm` to install :
`install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`.

2] Then, I setup `mix`:

```
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
        require("autoprefixer"),
    ]);
```

3] Then, I setup layers in the  `./resource/css/app.css` file:

```
@import "~tailwindcss/base";
@import "~tailwindcss/components";
@import "~tailwindcss/utilities";
```

4] Then, I added the full tailwind config in `tailwind.config.js` [as stated on the box](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#scaffolding-the-entire-default-configuration):
`npx tailwindcss init --full`
**Finally**, I ran the command `npm run dev` to publish all styles in the public `app.css` file.  But only the base styles was present in the public `app.css` file.
I am looking for a quick way to sample styles and remove the unnecessary bits.  Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of a "full tailwind 3.0 css library" like in previous versions, as combining all the variations available in version 3 would be too large. This is explained here, https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3#just-in-time-all-the-time

So it is compulsory to configure the purge settings, which is now called `content` in `tailwind.config.js`.

So by default, if Tailwind does not find any styles to add to the output, then all it will output is the base files, which is what it sounds like it is currently doing for you.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that tailwindcss added styles as needed.  So your assessment is correct and I seem to have done everything correctly EXCEPT, in Laravel the `app.css` file only updates if I `npm run watch` or `dev` and then refresh the page.  I had been running `npm run dev` and F5-ing like a mad, but only after uninstalling `autoprefixer` and `tailwindcss`; then reinstalling `tailwindcss` did it start to work.